# Hammerjs long press on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, hammer.js

I'm using Hammer.js v2.0.4 for this app that's being developed. The idea is when you tap a bottom a modal (modal-one) pops up, and if you press for 500ms (or more) another modal is shown (modal-two).

On desktop everything works fine.
On mobile, if you tap or press for less than 500ms the correct modal shown.
If you press for exactly 500ms opens the correct modal.
But if you press for more than 500ms nothings happens.

Is there any way show the correct modal if some user tap the bottom for >= 500ms?

Thanks in advance.

This is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var helpmodal = document.getElementById('help-modal');
var mc = new Hammer(helpmodal);

mc.on("press tap", function(ev) {
    if(ev.type == "tap")
        $('#help-modal').attr('data-target','#modal-one');
    else
        $('#help-modal').attr('data-target','#modal-two');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If anyone have the same problem, I found the solution:

Changing this:

```
$('#help-modal').attr('data-target','#modal-#');
```

For this:

```
$("#modal-#").modal("show");
```

That will make it work perfectly.
This is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var helpmodal = document.getElementById('help-modal');
var mc = new Hammer(helpmodal);

mc.on("press tap", function(ev) {
   if(ev.type == "tap")
      $("#modal-one").modal("show");
   else
      $("#modal-two").modal("show");
});
</script>
```